# Reading a Tx from a barcode scanner with a Arduino Mega 2560 - RS232

Tags: c, arduino, serial-port, barcode-scanner

For the past couple of days i have been trying to create a program which reads from a Tx of barcode scanner.
I have tried a bunch of different things such as different programs but also different scanners. 
A sample program that i wrote is for example:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial (50, 51);
unsigned char incomingByte;


void setup ()
{
    Serial.begin (9600);
    mySerial.begin (9600);
    Serial.println ("begin initial Serial!\n");
}

void loop ()
{
    while(mySerial.available () > 0)
    {
        incomingByte=mySerial.read ();
        Serial.print (incomingByte,HEX);
    }
    Serial.println ();
}
```

At this time i can not provide a proper connection diagram (will when i have a chance), but the arduino MEGA 2560 is connected with 3 wires to the barcode scanner, A Tx (pin 50), Rx (pin 51) and GND

background info on transmitted data:
startbit: 0x02
stopbit: 0x03

Ultimate goal: 
Scanner scans barcode, arduino reads the datastream and sends a output when it recognizes a code.

How do i achieve the ultimate goal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: What do you want to have happen?  What is happening?

Comment: Have you seen [this example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerialAvailable) which uses `pinmode`, and , do you need to use `mySerial.listen()`?

Comment: My question is, how to do i achieve the ultimate goal that i stated above (updated question too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arduino 2560 pin 50 and 51 are TTL level signals. You need to provide a RS-232 driver to invert and level shift the signal.

An example driver is MAX232CPE.

http://www.surplus-electronics-sales.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=15&products_id=828&gclid=CJv7vNWim8oCFYOEaQodSjQDFQ

Also, softwareserial supports an option to invert the logic level. From the Arduino page:

inverse_logic: is used to invert the sense of incoming bits (the default is normal logic). If set, SoftwareSerial treats a LOW (0 volts on the pin, normally) on the Rx pin as a 1-bit (the idle state) and a HIGH (5 volts on the pin, normally) as a 0-bit. It also affects the way that it writes to the Tx pin. Default value is false.

Warning: You should not connect devices which output serial data outside the range that the Arduino can handle, normally 0V to 5V, for a board running at 5V, and 0V to 3.3V for a board running at 3.3V.

[Arduino SoftwareSerial Reference page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerialConstructor)

Comment: Okay, that could do the trick, but can it be done without a RS-232 driver? The group before us also did not use a rs 232 driver.